# tweety api giving a socket error

Tags: python, twitter, text-mining, tweepy

I am a newbie to text mining and python.I am trying to collect data from twitter for my project and trying some progras of tweepy.I have started with this tutorial here

http://sentdex.com/sentiment-analysisbig-data-and-python-tutorials-algorithmic-trading/how-to-use-the-twitter-api-1-1-to-stream-tweets-in-python/

and tried this example

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

ckey='62iPwUDN82N6G78FE05P1b4bi'
csecret='CneDixa0FBubPgFpxuZoRPWi8RUcSuGIC9Gstjzf1hVzYDGuLa'
atoken='2506572247-3LcLGZvrfZ7bGVYF5ZoxkMEatrV7wn3R5Kbfrg8'
asecret='zzI73HDbtvZlWoR3sHyf6p3wQNCaRHGc1XC8ZqdZJH6QV'

class listener(StreamListener) :
    def on_data( self ,data) :
        print data
        return True

    def on_error( self ,status):

        print status



auth=OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken,asecret)

twitterStream=Stream(auth,listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

But it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 24, in <module>
    twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy-2.0-py2.7.egg\tweepy\streaming.py",
 line 230, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy-2.0-py2.7.egg\tweepy\streaming.py",
 line 171, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy-2.0-py2.7.egg\tweepy\streaming.py",
 line 106, in _run
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1172, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable n
etwork
```

i am not using any ide for python and writing it in notepad++ ,running it in command prompt. i am using windows7 OS.i have installed tweepy 2.0

Edit: I am behind a proxy server(Authentication not required)